# Allowing custom attribute to element with htmlpurifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

Got stuck half-way through my little process, need help with this last step.

Needed to add a custom element to accept a custom `book` element that would be passed through a textarea form.

```
$dirty = 'you should check this out: <book author="me">my book title</book>!';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'book');
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addElement('book',  'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
echo $purifier->purify($dirty);
```

Returns: 
`you should check this out: <book>my book title</book>!`

But it is stripping out the `author="me"`

If I add in the standard htmlpurifier attr allowance, such as:

```
`$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'book[author]');`
```

it returns error:
`Attribute 'author' in element 'book' not supported`

I need it so that the `author="me"` can be included or not included.

Can somebody please share the code change/addition I need to get the `author="me"` to be allowed - thanks!

I am running htmlpurifier 4.6.0

Comment: Were the docs in http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html insufficient?

Comment: Yep, otherwise I wouldn't have posted this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `$def->addAttribute('book', 'author', 'CDATA');` after your `$def->addElement(...)` call?